# Shopify Plus Enabling Checkout.liquid

Tags: shopify, shopify-template

I'm a developer who works on a recently updated Shopify plus store. The problem is that I can't add `checkout.liquid` from the layout of the theme, it is supposed to be in the select but there is no such option. I'm using Shopify partner to connect to the store if that relates to the case.

[image]

Comment: You can contact shopify support and ask them to enable it for the store

Comment: @SubhrajyotiDas that's the actual answer to the question. You should add it as an answer instead of a comment so that its able to be marked as the correct answer.

Comment: Look at here https://help.route.com/hc/en-us/articles/360048444853-Shopify-Plus-Enable-checkout-liquid-

Answer (score 4):

You can contact Shopify support and ask them to enable it for you