# How To Hide/Set default for Postcode In Shopify Checkout Page?

Tags: shopify, liquid, shopping-cart, shopify-template

How I can hide/Set Default Value for PostCode on Checkout Page in Shopify.

Actually, Is the Core Code for Cart in Shopify Same for all Templates?

Guys, I need to hide or set default Postcode Because My Country doesn't use the postcode.

[image]

Comment: Your purchase will not go through if the customer does not enter postcode. Can you elaborate why do you want to hide the postcode?

Comment: You mean cart or Checkout ?

Comment: @BilalAkbar Yes. Question have been updated

Comment: The postcode cannot be hidden if you are on a basic shopify plan. You need checkout.liquid to be available to you in order to hide and provide a default value

Comment: @SubhrajyotiDas Guys, I need to hide or set default Postcode Because My Country doesn't use the postcode.

Comment: I understand. You need checkout.liquid to be available to you in order to hide and provide a default value. checkout.liquid is only available to Shopify Plus customers. If you are not a Plus customer you won't be able to achive what you want

Comment: @SubhrajyotiDas How I can Find Checkout.liquid, I updated my plan to Shopify Plus ?!

Comment: @MikeDarwish you would need to contact Shopify Support to enable the liquid page for you. Check answer here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58764316/shopify-plus-enabling-checkout-liquid